# How to add swift compiler to objective c project

Tags: xcode, swift

When I tried to import a Swift Framework into my existing objective c project, I'm having trouble finding the swift compiler in the Build Settings. When I searched about using swift code in objective c, they are talking about bridging header. However, since there is no swift compiler in my build settings, there is no where to config the compiler. My Xcode version is 6.3.2, I don't know how could other people have swift compiler by default?

The only walk around is to re-create a project with swift. Then replace everything with objective c. I don't want to re-create the project.

UPDATE:

Just for future references: When import a swift library (project) into existing objective-c project. Create a temporary swift class file, **`compile it`** (This is what I missed) and delete. You will have "Swift Compiler" appears in build settings. Then you can follow other guides like Apple documents to config bridging headers and other stuffs.

Comment: Can you add some details about what you mean when you're talking about importing a Swift framework?  Does your project have Swift source code in it?  How does your project setup look like?  Are there any Swift files in the "Compile Sources" section of the build phases for any of your targets?

Comment: Thanks for the update you added. When I simply added .swift files from another project it didn't switch on the Swift compile options.

The key was adding a temporary .swift file, which can be deleted later.

Comment: The key was using the "new file" dialog to add a .swift file, even if it is just the default content (or you could probably copy the contents of an imported file, delete it, create another with the same name and then paste,)

Comment: As of Xcode 9 at least, it looks like it is not enough to compile, then remove the file, as Xcode figures out that no Swift code is reachable and the project settings are updated not to include the Swift runtime (ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES set to NO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add the Swift code to your project. Xcode will recognize it and compile it properly. There's no need to make any changes in the project settings.

You will need a bridging header file to call your own Objective-C code (not Cocoa code) from your Swift code.

To call Swift code, you just need to get the #import right.

For either of these, search here on SO. Then post a new, specific question if you can't get it working.

Comment: Thanks, I did import the swift class but didn't compile. After I compile the swift compiler showed up in Build Settings.